# Select variable based on string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to change the text of 6 card titles with jQuery but I have 30 lines of code just for an if/else statement.

I've tried to fix it by only checking the **`i`** value and then `return currentID[num]` but it's not working

Javascript:

```
const name1 = ['first 1', 'first 2', 'first 3', 'first 4', 'first 5', 'first6'];
const name2 = ['second 1', 'second 2', 'second 3', 'second 4', 'second 5', 'second 6';
const name3 = ['third 1', 'third 2', 'third 3', 'third 4', 'third 5', 'third 6'];
const name4 = ['fourth 1', 'fourth 2', 'fourth 3', 'fourth 4', 'fourth 5', 'fourth 6'];

const currentID = this.id;

$('.card-title').text((i) => {
    //Here there's an awkward if statement that checks the "currentID" for one
    //of the arrays above and then selects a value based on "i"
    //I've tried changing it to the code below but it returns each letter of the
    //const name, not the value

    return currentID[i/2];
});
```

I need that if statement to return the value of the arrays above.
This `$('.card-title').text((i) => {}` creates a loop and increases the **`i`** value by 2 each time. So I need to check that number, and select a different value of the array.
So, currentID[0] should return "first 1", "second 1", "third 1" or "fourth 1" based on the selected id; but because currentID returns a string, the if statement gives me single letters instead of the array.

Comment: Appreciate that you've provided *some* code, but it's not enough to tell what you're doing, what you're trying to do and what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Why are you trying to get `currentID[x]` while `currentID` is not a number?

Comment: Looks like that's still missing a few key elements for us to know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: cureentID returns a string named: name1, name2, name3 or name4 and I want to select every element of the IDs array

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but instead of doing tons of if statements, just do this: `return currentID[i/2]`

Comment: @JoseHenriqueFelipetto It helped, but because it returns a string, the result is that every card changes it's title to a letter from the currentID: 'n' 'a' 'm' 'e' '1'